# Woocommerce custom downloadable product type

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have create a custom WC product type, which is defined as follow:

```
class WC_Product_My_Product extends WC_Product_Simple {

 public function __construct( $product ) {

    $this->product_type = 'my_product';

    $this->virtual = 'yes';
    $this->downloadable = 'yes';
    $this->manage_stock = 'no';
 }
}
```

As you can see the product is, how intended, a virtual product consisting in downloadable files.
I am using Jquery to define the settings to be displayed when the product is selected.
I am showing also the fields usually displayed for a simple product where virtual and downloadable are selected.

```
 /*
 * Apply same settings as virtual / downloadable files
*/
jQuery( '.options_group.show_if_downloadable' ).addClass( 'show_if_my_product' );
jQuery( '.hide_if_virtual' ).addClass( 'hide_if_my_product' );

 jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'woocommerce-product-type-change', function( event, select_val, select ) {

    if ( select_val == 'my_product' ) {
      jQuery( '.show_if_my_product' ).show();
      jQuery( '.hide_if_my_product' ).hide();
    } else {
      jQuery( '.show_if_my_product' ).show();
      jQuery( '.hide_if_my_product' ).hide();
   }
```

Now, the problem is that the "virtual" and "downloadable" checkboxes are not selected when selecting My Product from the dropdown list, since they are not by default for simple products. As woo commerce simply uses JQuery to show / hide different fields for different product types (but the fields are still there), when the New Product is added Wordpress stores their values among the posts meta. Thus, unless I remember to first check on virtual and downloadable before switching from the default Simple Product to My Product, my download settings and links will not be stored.

Now, the solution is rather simple (and is working). Manually (err... using jQuery) checking the "virtual" and "downloadable" checkbox. Like so:

```
jQuery( '#_virtual' ).attr( 'checked' , true );
jQuery( '#_downloadable' ).attr( 'checked' , true );
```

Now, as I said, this works, so there really is nothing to "fix". However, I am not too satisfied by this solution as it looks like a work around.
It is my understanding (perhaps wrong?) that the My Product class already defines them as being virtual and downloadable, and that they shouldn't thus follow what a hidden input field which is there only for other products is saying.
Perhaps there is something missing in my php where I defined the product? Or perhaps I am misunderstanding entirely what the "virtual" and "downloadable" properties of the WC_Product subclass mean?

If this is a proper solution, should I then simply remove the definition as virtual and downloadable in the php class?

In the end, this solution works and I can't see any major problem with it, but it still seems as something is missing and shouldn't be done this way. Am I only being paranoid?

Answer (score 2):

i found solution to fix this problem. you just need to add this code

```
add_action( 'product_type_options', 'wc_custom_product_type_options' );
function wc_custom_product_type_options($options){
    $options['downloadable']['wrapper_class'] = 'show_if_simple show_if_my_product';
    $options['virtual']['wrapper_class'] = 'show_if_simple show_if_my_product';
    return $options;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this just affect how they are displayed?

Comment: yes, thats why you need to add $this->virtual = 'yes'; and $this->downloadable = 'yes'; to constructor